# Facebook App Invites iOS SDK v4.1 App Crashes while Return to App

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-invite

I am using Facebook iOS SDK v4.1 in iOS application. Application is in Development State. I am trying to invite Facebook friends to share Application.
I am following [This Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios).

I have Created appLink. Also Clear about AppLink. Using Facebook test Users, I have successfully called FBSDKAppInviteDialog. I can also Select Friends to send invitation.

My Problem is,

While i Click on CANCEL Button, view Comes from Facebook App to my Application and app getting crashed. Error :

```
    2015-05-07 15:45:03.065 [1795:576380] app invite result: {
    didComplete = 1;
}
2015-05-07 15:45:03.075 [1795:576380] -[__NSCFDictionary valueForComplexKeyPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14fafe40
2015-05-07 15:45:03.081 [1795:576380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary valueForComplexKeyPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14fafe40'
```

While Select Friends Successfully And Select Invite Button, it comes back to application and app get crashed.  Error :

```
2015-05-07 15:48:17.777 [1803:578622] app invite result: {
    completionGesture = cancel;
    didComplete = 1;
}
2015-05-07 15:48:17.791 [1803:578622] -[__NSCFDictionary valueForComplexKeyPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176965e0
2015-05-07 15:48:17.800 [1803:578622] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary valueForComplexKeyPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176965e0'
```

Comment: Are you sure this is SDK related? What's the stack trace? The SDK doesn't use the valueForComplexKeyPath: selector anywhere.

Comment: I am using Facebook App Invite Delegate method to determine Facebook app invite completion state.  https://gist.github.com/vinhnx/817fe5de3dd5c88e491e

Comment: valueForComplexKeyPath: is not part of NSDictionary. It looks like it's part of MTJSONDictionary? Are you using that? In any case, this is not SDK related.

Comment: @Ming Li Thanks for pointing this out. Now Application successfully go to Facebook Page and again successfully return back to Application. But every time success results for  `appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults` will be `didComplete = 1;`  does it meant  `didFinished` ?

Comment: See https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#onsuccess